# Bloomberg Ticker from Index ISIN and Index Key

Tags: index-fund, market-indexes, isin

Is there a way to find the Bloomberg Ticker for an Index given the Index ISIN and Index Key?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the API. `=BDP(US0846707026&" ISIN", "PX_LAST")`. You can also cell reference the ISIN (standard Excel logic).

No need to get the BBG ticker. Also `F1F1` is the help desk, which operates 24/7 and can help with that within minutes.

The link to `HELP DAPI` is `{LPHP DAPI:0:1 2571060<Go>}` but it will only work for Bloomberg users (and likely change over time).

In general, ISINs are not unique. They will then reflect the settings you have on your `CNDF`  and `PDFQ` settings. You can do something like this though:

```
=BDP(BDP("DE0008404005"&" ISIN","EQY_FUND_TICKER")&" Equity","px last")
```

Alternatively, you can specify the exchange code after the ISIN (provided you know that).

```
=BDP("DE0008404005 GY"&" ISIN","px last")
```

There are lots of nuances, and ISINs for options are not supported in the API. Yet, you can do all sorts of things with the API such as directly using ISIN, SEDOL, VALOREN, CEDEL, EUROCLEAR etc., which makes it quick to get all the info you need. If you simply type the ISIN in the command line, you would also be able to load the security.

[image]

Overall, I still think it is best to simply ask the help desk for these questions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will get you the whole way there, but: https://www.openfigi.com/api